# How to debug failed load_theme_textdomain()?

Tags: translation, multi-language, textdomain

I made my theme ready for translation. My `text domain` is `my_theme` and my `.po` and `.mo` (de_DE.po and de_DE.mo) files are located in a subfolder `languages` in my themes folder.

In my `functions.php` I added the following code:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup');
function my_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain('my_theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
```

My backend language is "German" but the translation isn’t loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

`load_theme_textdomain()` returns `TRUE` on success and `FALSE` if no file was found. For debugging try the following change:

```
function my_theme_setup(){
    $path = get_template_directory() . '/languages';
    $result = load_theme_textdomain('my_theme', $path );

    if ( $result )
        return;

   $locale = apply_filters( 'theme_locale', get_locale(), 'my_theme' );
   die( "Could not find $path/$locale.mo." );
}
```